# TabBar icon two selected in viewDidLoad in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

i want to open my UITabBarController using the Main.storyboard like in the image below. The problem is that i present a different ViewController modally from the Second View and i want to go back from this ViewController to my previous ViewController. How could i load my UITabBarController with the Second icon selected? is there any code for the viewDidLoad you guys know?

I also thought about an Unwind Segue but everything i try doesn't work.

optimally i would like to restore my selected tab bar icon.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OsTf.png)

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bny5G.png)

Comment: So you want to go from "View Controller" to "Item 1" instead of "Item 2"?

Comment: i want to go from "View Controller" to "Item 2"

Comment: Ok is your Segue to "View Controller" from "Item 1" or "Item 2"?

Comment: but "Item 1" is always selected when i load my UITabBarController

Comment: My Segue is from "Item 2" to "View Controller"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you seem to have a segue from "Second View" to the "Tab Bar Controller" and it always leads to "Item 1".

**Ok... finally the right answer:**

1) Modal segue from "Second View" to VC

2) IBAction from button in VC with the following code:

```
 @IBAction func test(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // Swift 2: self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) 
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
}
```

The idea is simple: use a modal segue to pop the VC and then just dismiss it instead of using a segue, which always hides the tab bar afterwards.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but my Segue to "Second View" only opens the View but without the TabBar.

Comment: Ok apparently this only works when embedding a Navigation Controller to both Tabs and in order to go back from VC to Second View just use the "< Back" Button from the Navigation Controller. Embedding a Navigation Controller works by selecting the VC like in my screenshot and going to "Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller"

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment you don't need a segue to go back - you can use the navigation controller instead - otherwise the tab bar will get hidden

Comment: Is there any other way to load the TabBar with the different icons selected? i created already about 50 VC for my App and i would like to use the design i created for them.@IBAction func BackToTabBar(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        
        
    } maybe something like this?

Comment: Try using `override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool){self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false}` in your "Second View"

Comment: If i open my "Second View" now, only a black screen appears.

Comment: thank you really much, but i really don't get how i could fix this issue, i really spent days with this.

Comment: OK, check out my updated answer :) I promise it works now!

Comment: i used your code and it still dons`t work. I'm sorry if i missed something. I'm really getting tired of this problem. See my Screenshot in the updated Question.

Comment: You are using it in the wrong place. Use my code inside your ViewController not your TabViewController. "View Controller" should be a normal UIViewController. Look close at the code in my screenshot

Comment: I will go to sleep now, thank you so so much for your help. I will try it tomorrow again. Maybe sleep is the solution for my problem:)

Comment: It always says "Value of type "View Controller" has no member "dismiss" :/

Comment: Ok it could be my bad.. I'm on Swift 3. Try self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

Comment: Oh my god it finally works, i really don't know how to thank you for that. Can i help you getting points or something on stackoverflow.com? honestly i just created my account before i asked my question.

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to upvote the answer by clicking the ^ button next to my answer :) Not sure if you can upvote answers already but you can try :)